# TFS 2010 - check-out while rebasing branches

Tags: tfs, rebase

While I am rebasing our branch, rest of the team continues working on code. Rebase lasts about 1-2 hours. I'm doing it from merge in context menu when you right click the folder to merge, so nothing special here.

Team members check-out code, alter it but they do not check in. What risks this approach has? What is the best practice for this situation? How your team handles such cases?

Comment: Can you give us some more information about the process you use to rebase the branch?

Comment: hi james, I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're suggesting is a fairly standard approach and just to make sure I understand the question, here is a scenario.

There is a `Main` branch. From this `Main` branch 2 development branches have been created (`devA` and `devB`) these branches will be used to make changes to the code for 2 seperate projects.

The development in `devA` has reached a stable state and has been merged in to the `Main` branch. Now you want to merge the changes from `Main` in to `devB`

In `devB` the developers have been coding changes and have a number of files checked out. You don't want to make the developers check in their changes to `devB` and you don't want to initiate a code freeze whilst the rebasing takes place.

If the developers have been checking in changes to `devB` on a regular basis since the branch was created, you will porbably see merge conflicts when you try to merge the `devA` changes from the `Main` branch. Someone familiar with the code and requirements for both "projects" will need to help resolve those merge conflicts. Once the conflicts have been resolved you'll probably want to check that the code compiles and that any unit tests run and pass. If you have compilation errors or unit tests fail then this will need investigating.

Once you're happy that the merge from `Main` to `devB` has been sucessful then the developers with files checked out in `devB` can start to check in changes. If the files they have checked out were not changed as part of the merge from `Main` then the files will check in as normal. If however they have files checked out that were updated as part of the merge, TFS will bring up the merge conflict resolution tool and the developers will need to resolve any conflicts before they can check in the code.

Hopefully the above is resaonably close to the process you're currently following? If I've missed anything, or missed the point entirely then let me know.

This isn't as nice as it could be, but it's a common approach and one that we use.

The risk to this approach is that you could end up spending a lot of time fixing merge conflicts, especially if you have a large codebase with a lot of developers changing the code in a lot of branches.

To mitigate any problems, it's best to rebase as early and as often as possible. Early because if you save everything up till the end of `devA's` project, then the changes could have a significant impact on `devB`. Often because the number of conflicts per merge is minimised, making conflict resolution simpler and less error prone.

Setting up a "continuous integration" build will also help as you'll see compilation problems sooner rather than later. If you're using TFS 2010 then Gated Checking may also be helpful.

I'm not 100% sure that this answers your question so let me know if I've missed anything

Comment: you have understood my question perfectly fine. thanks for the answer.